# Count the number of matching rows for high magnitude counts (100,000+)

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, nosql, counter

#### Objective:

Get the number of times something happened between two times when the order of magnitude of the count is 100,000 - 10,000,000.

#### Current implementation:

- Using PostgreSQL
- Each "incident" is recorded as a separate row in a table

The columns:

- Incident type
- Date-Time that it occurred

The query to get the count (pseudocode):

```
COUNT rows WHERE time_occurred > <begin_time> AND time_occurred < <end_time>
```

#### The problem:

This works, but the query is very inefficient and takes about 40 seconds to respond. As I understand it, PostgreSQL is not a good database to use for this type of query.

I sat down and thought up a few ways that this type of query could be indexed and executed in O(log n) time so I know t is possible.

What tools should I be using to do this? Should we be using a different database to store the count rows? Is there a package we could install on top of PostgreSQL to do this easily? What are our options?

#### Note:

Not sure if I was clear about this. The result of `COUNT` should be on the order of 100,000 - 10,000,000. This means that the number of rows that match the query would be on the order of 100,000 - 10,000,000. The actual number of rows in the table is an order of magnitude more.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Just for the record: your table is properly indexed, and when you run an `EXPLAIN` of your query, it sais that the indices are in fact used?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is indexed fine. As I understand it, the problem is that there are 100,000+ results to the query, so even though its indexed, and it doesn't have to actually pull the rows out, the system still has to count each result, which is O(n) if 'n' is the number of results.

Comment: How _exactly_ is the `WHERE` clause of your query? Provided that `time_occured` is indexed, and that no calculation are done on the values, 1M rows should be no problem for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` and other details per http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info . This query *really* shouldn't take 40 seconds even on a slow machine. Also, is there an index on `(time_occurred)`? There should be.

Comment: Not really sure how to answer some of these questions. I've been told that PostgreSQL is not the best tool for this job. Wondering what actually is the best tool for this job and the general strategy we should using to count things of this nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre-PostgreSQL 9.2 the implementation of MVCC required any query to visit each row of the table to check if that version of the row was visible to the current transaction. This would happen, even if the query only involved indexed columns. This manifests as slow counts on large tables, even for simple cases.

PostgreSQL 9.2 implements [index only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans), which may help alleviate this issue for some workloads.

If you are stuck below v9.2, there are some known workarounds if you only need an approximate row count on a simple query. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate .

Answer (score 1):

Keep a table of incidents aggregated by day.

```
create table incidents_agreggated_by_day (
    "day" date primary key, total integer
);
```

Everyday run:

```
insert into events_agreggated_by_day ("day", total) values
select date_trunc('day', time_occurred), count(*) total
from incidents
where 
    time_occurred < current_date
    and date_trunc('day', time_occurred) not in (
        select "day" from incidents_agreggated_by_day
    )
group by 1
```

Suppose you want the total between '2013-01-01 10:37' and '2013-03-02 11:20':

```
select
(
    select sum(total)
    from incidents_aggregated_by_day
    where "day" >= '2013-01-02'::date and "day" < '2013-03-02'::date
) +
(
    select count(*)
    from incidents
    where 
        time_ocurred >= '2013-01-01 10:37':timestamp
        and time_ocurred < '2013-01-02'
        or
        time_ocurred <= '2013-03-02 11:20':timestamp
        and time_ocurred >= '2013-01-02'
) total
```

In instead of reading 100 million rows you will read hundreds or thousands. If properly indexed it will be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to partition the table.  This guy seems to have solved a very similar problem with partitioning:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/performance-testing-between-partitioned-and-non-partitioned-postgresql-tables-part-3/

My concern with using his approach would be maintainability.  In his example (you have to click through to part 1 of the tutorial to see how he created the partitions), he manually creates each child table and has hard-coded routing to the child tables in a trigger.  If your table is constantly growing, you would be doing a lot of DBA work.

However, he does seem to get a big performance boost.  So, if you can figure out how to make it more maintainable, this might be a good way to proceed.

Comment: I can see how you could shard the database into pieces, then do a bunch of parallel queries against the data at the same time. Is this what the article is about? Are there "off-the-shelf" tools that can be used to do this more easily. Seems like the kind of thing that shouldn't be coded out right?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the problem that dimensional modelling and data warehousing is designed to solve.

A previous project I worked on built a data warehouse in Ruby in a couple of weeks in order to deal with queries like this, and exposed it to the main app with a simple REST API.  Basically you extract your data and transform it into a 'Star Schema', which is highly optimized for queries like the one you describe.

Postgresql is well suited to be the data warehouse database.

It is a very detailed subject, and a great starter resource is this:  [http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247)